# Nginx upstream to same server with different bind interfaces

Tags: nginx

I have nginx running on a host with two different network interfaces. There is a single upstream host which I can connect to via one local interface at a time. This situation is due to the underlying network routing, traffic will flow over one of two different network paths.

I need to bind each server in the upstream to a different interface. Something like this:

```
stream {
  upstream remote {
    server 1.2.3.4:12345; # bind interface 1
    server 1.2.3.4:12345 backup; # bind interface 2
  }

  server {
    listen 12345;
    proxy_pass remote;
  }
}
```

I've tried solving this with an intermediate unix socket, but because nginx can connect to the unix socket always, it never tries the backup. When a connection cannot be made over interface 1 a connection over interface 2 is never tried.

```
stream {
  server {
    listen unix:/tmp/1.sock;
    proxy_pass 1.2.3.4:12345;
    proxy_bind <interface 1>;
  }

  server {
    listen unix:/tmp/2.sock;
    proxy_pass 1.2.3.4:12345;
    proxy_bind <interface 2>;
  }

  upstream remote {
    server unix:/tmp/1.sock;
    server unix:/tmp/2.sock backup;
  }

  server {
    listen 12345;
    proxy_pass remote;
  }
}
```

*EDIT*

I tried another approach by setting the proxy_bind at the stream level, but when the primary upstream is down, connecting to the unix socket fails with `bind(<interface 1>) (22:invalid argument)` (cannot bind to a network interface when connecting to unix domain socket).

```
stream {
  proxy_bind <interface 1>;

  server {
    listen unix:/tmp/2.sock;
    proxy_pass 1.2.3.4:12345;
    proxy_bind <interface 2>;
  }

  upstream remote {
    server 1.2.3.4:12345;
    server unix:/tmp/2.sock backup;
  }

  server {
    listen 12345;
    proxy_pass remote;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If the host is configured to route traffic over interface 1 by default then my edited solution without the top level `proxy_bind` will have the desired effect.

I checked the host routing with:

```
$ ip route get 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4 via <gateway> dev eth0 src <interface 1> uid 1000 
    cache
```